# Is there a way to filter odd or even indices in a presto array?

Tags: presto, trino

I have a presto array and I need to filter out odd indices no matter what the values in an array are.

Array = ['no', 'matter', 'what', 'is, 'here']

Desired result = ['matter', 'is']

I've tried quite a lot of different variations of *sequence(2, cardinality(Array), 2)* but nothing seem to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up zipping the array with an index array that I created

```sql
zip(ar, sequence(1, cardinality(ar), 1))
```

then I filtered `x[2]` on `x -> x[2]%2=0` and selected only `x -> x[1]` with transform.

Some other suggestion in a different place was unnesting with ordinality, filtering on ordinality column and then aggregating back.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - generate sequence of only needed indexes (for even ones - start with 2 and set step to 2) and use `transform` on it:

```sql
WITH dataset(arr) AS ( values (array[1,2,3,4,5]) )

SELECT transform(sequence(2, cardinality(arr), 2), i -> arr[i])
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [2, 4] |